# Acessar arquivos xml de um diretório c#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma função que recebe um arquivo xml como parâmetro.

```
  public void lerXML(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        XmlNodeList xnCNPJ = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("emit");
        XmlNodeList xnNFE = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ide");
        XmlNodeList xnChaveNFE = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("infProt");
        ...
    }
```

Quero aplicar essa função à todos os arquivos de um diretório

No caso, estou fazendo assim:

```
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Diretorio);

            foreach (FileInfo a in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                lerXML(a.FullName);
            }
```

Porém, aparece o seguinte erro:

> "Não é possível converter de 'string' para System.Xml.XmlDocument"

Tentei deixar assim: `lerXML(a);` porém mesmo erro.

Como poderia realizar essa conversão?

Comment: Considere usar [`XDocument`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8) ao invés de `XMLDocument`.

Comment: qual seria a diferença entre os dois?

Comment: `XDocument` é muito mais simple de utilizar e manipular. Também não possui uma falha no processo de validação(XSD) onde em caso de erros de validação o `XMLDocument` não permite buscar o elemento ou atributo que causou o erro de validação(apesar de estar documentada essa facilidade na prática não foi implementada).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa carregar o arquivo já que o seu método espera um `XmlDocument`... quando você faz isso `lerXML(a.FullName)`, está passando uma `string` e não uma representação do documento.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Diretorio);
foreach (FileInfo a in dirInfo.GetFiles())
{
    var documentoXml = new XmlDocument();
        documentoXml.Load(a.FullName);                

        lerXML(documentoXml);
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, funcionou certinho, obrigado hehe